# Any quick ways to serialize input data to List<object> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, serialization, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's say I have an object:

```
Person
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

On the client side, the user gets a table with a whole bunch of input texts for adding/editing these "people".

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName"/></td>
</tr>
```

The controller action is expecting a `List<Person>`:

```
public ActionResult SavePeople (List<Person> people)
{ ..... }
```

Input data is submitted to the Action with AJAX call.  What is the easiest way to serialize all that input data?  I don't want to manually build a JavaScript array, etc.  Something like `$('table input').serialize()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's already wrapped in a form...

```
$('form').serialize();
```

Comment: Right, and then it serializes them as FirstName=val&LastName=val,FirstName=val2&LastName=val2 and then on the server side, it doesn't get serialized into List<Person>